# Appdelegate presentviewcontroller

Tags: ios, rootviewcontroller

I'm trying to display the webpage google.com using the following. For some reason it's not presenting the controller with google.com. Can anyone help?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    SFSafariViewController *vc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: what issue you are facing ? black screen or something error ?

Comment: Yes black screen after the loading page

Comment: Use a storyboard and set the entry point to this view controller. Remove then the code in didFinishLaunchWithOptions and just keep "return YES;"

Comment: @locoboy check demo. and please mark as right if it helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    SFSafariViewController *vc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

            SFSafariViewController *vc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
            self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: try this it is working for me, I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

How to use SFSafariview controller first check on this link.

[SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SFSafariViewController)

Moreover you can check full tutorial in below link also,

**Example 1 :-**  **[iOS-SafariViewControllerFinishedProject](https://github.com/tutsplus/iOS-SafariViewControllerFinishedProject)**

**Example 2 :-** **[ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller--cms-24260)**

From github you can also download Demo Project. [IOS9SafariViewControllerTutorial Example](https://github.com/ioscreator/ioscreator/tree/master/IOS9SafariViewControllerTutorial)

**Edit :-**

I have make **demo** for you **without storyboard**. please check on below link.

**[Safari without storyboard demo](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00488145735447995079)**

Output :-

[image]

Comment: I'm not using a storyboard

Comment: have you set @property(nonatomic, weak) id< SFSafariViewControllerDelegate > delegate??

Comment: check edited answer. and follow tutorial from second link.

Comment: I have also added demo project link. second demo is good please download it and check it.

Comment: for the github project it looks like it uses a storyboard. also I shouldn't need to define the delegate to load the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105354/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-locoboy).

Answer (score 0):

Move the `SafariViewController` presentation code to `viewDidAppear` of your `RootViewController`. If your `RootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, move it to the `viewDidAppear` of your Navigation Controller's `topViewController`